# Why are python string reverse methods are returning the normal string?

Tags: python, reverse

I tried 2 methods:

`s = ['hello'] s[::-1]`

and I got back `['hello']`

as well as `s.reverse()`

and I didn't get back anything, and when I typed s afterwards I got back `['hello']`

Any tips on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: you are reversing a `list` with **one** element (which does nothing)... did you mean to reverse the element inside the list?

Comment: In your own words, when you write `['hello']`, what do you think the `[]` are for?

Answer (score 0):

`s` is not a string in your case, it is a list with one element, which is string.
define s as

```
s = 'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

Becuase You are reversing a list, try

```
s[0].reverse()
```